# Why is a paginated query slower than a plain one with Spring Data?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Given I have a simple query:

```
List<Customer> findByEntity(String entity);
```

This query returns 7k records in 700ms.

```
Page<Customer> findByEntity(String entity, Pageable pageable);
```

this query returns 10 records in 1080ms. I am aware of the additional count query for pagination, but still something seems off. Also one strange thing I've noticed is that if I increase page size from 10 to 1900, response time is exactly the same around 1080 ms.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It might indeed be the count query that's expensive here. If you insist on knowing about the total number of elements matching in the collection there's unfortunately no way around that additional query. However there are two possibilities to avoid more of the overhead if you're able to sacrifice on information returned:

1. **Using `Slice` as return type** — `Slice` doesn't expose a method to find out about the total number of elements but it allows you to find out about whether a next slice is available. We avoid the count query here by reading one more element than requested and using its (non-)presence as indicator of the availability of a next slice.
2. **Using `List` as return type** — That will simply apply the pagination parameters to the query and return the window of elements selected. However it leaves you with no information about whether subsequent data is available.

Answer (score 4):

Method with pagination runs two query:

```
1) select count(e.id) from Entity e //to get number of total records
2) select e from Entity e limit 10 [offset 10] //'offset 10' is used for next pages
```

The first query runs slow on 7k records, IMHO.

Upcoming release [Ingalis](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Ingalls) of Spring Data will use improved algorithm for paginated queries ([more info](https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/30/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-ingalls#pagination)).

> Any suggestions?

I think using a paginated query with 7k records it's useless. You should limit it.